# Select distinct in BIRT from flat files

Tags: csv, birt

I have a CSV file that look something like this:

```
Test, Result, Case, Type
------------------------
t1  , pass  , c1  , Functional
t2  , fail  , c1  , Operational
t3  , fail  , c2  , Functional
t4  , fail  , c2  , Operational
```

I'd like to define a new dataset that is a single-column list of the unique values of the 'Type' column:

```
TestType
--------
Functional
Operational
Regression
```

If I were hitting a database, I could use some SQL like

```
SELECT DISTINCT type
FROM thatFile
```

But it seems in BIRT (Actuate BIRT Designer v11) I don't have that luxury.  Right now I'm working with data objects...should I be using an information object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot I asked this, so I may as well jot down what I did.  Turns out that Information Objects will indeed be a fine route.  Otherwise, a data object is equally okay to use - create a new dataset and use 'distinct' in the 'query' tab of the wizard.